# Advanced SQL statement executing checkbox checked

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

I have HTML code with checkbox and submit button as below

```
<form action="checkboxes.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Yes">4K</input>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" ></input>
</form>
```

And in my PHP I have a file "config.php" that his function is to connect to my database:

```
<?php
/* Database connection */

$sDbHost = 'localhost';
$sDbName = 'testowanie';
$sDbUser = 'root';
$sDbPwd = '';
$dbcon = mysqli_connect ($sDbHost, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd, $sDbName);
?>
```

And a second PHP file:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM monitory";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget)or die("Can't connect to the database");

if(isset($_POST['checkbox1']) && 
   $_POST['checkbox1'] == 'Yes')
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       echo '.';
       echo $row['cena'];
   }
}
?>
```

This all three connected files each others do that if the checkbox is checked this SQL statement are executed: `SELECT cena FROM monitory;` but I want to execute this statement `"SELECT * FROM monitory WHERE cena=1000;`
I tried to do this like around 2 hours but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is but perhaps you want to add the `WHERE` condition *inside* the `if` statement and execute / loop *after* the `if` statement?

Comment: yes this is it, ps: and sorry if i make some errors in my english but i'm french and i don't really speak english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So You want to choose one of two different queries according to input conditions. Then do it so :-)

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['checkbox1']))
    $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM monitory WHERE cena = 1000";
else
    $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM monitory";

$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget)or die("Can't connect to the database");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '.';
    echo $row['cena'];
}
```